# Vue and Firebase RTDB connection

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

I have followed few different tutorials, read numerous posts on SO, but still my firebase RTDB won't connect. It doesnt even throw any error.

At this point my file in ***db/database.js*** looks like this (I stripped it from connection data):

```
 
const firebaseConfig = {
   apiKey: "key",
   authDomain: "",
   databaseURL: "https://database_name.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app",
   projectId: "",
   storageBucket: "",
   messagingSenderId: "",
   appId: ""
 };


 firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
 const firebaseDb = firebase.database()

 export default firebaseDb
```

the method that I use to call the database ref in ***store/index.js***

```
dbReadSettings() {
    console.log("I'm here");
    let settings = firebaseDb.ref('userSettings/', function(error) { console.log(error) });
            settings.on('value', (snapshot) => {
                const data = snapshot.val();
                console.log(data)
            }, function(error) {
                console.log(error) })
        }
```

The result is none – **the console logs out I'm here" and then nothing else** (I tried many different ways). I checked the path and the documentation but it does not connect at all. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the ref method only receives one parameter.

```
dbReadSettings() {
  console.log("I'm here");
  let settings = firebaseDb.ref('userSettings/');

  settings.on('value', (snapshot) => {
    const data = snapshot.val();
    console.log(data)
  }, (error) => {
     console.log(error)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That first callback you have is not needed, and will in fact never be called. Since you attach the listener inside that callback, the listener will never be attached.

You can easily check this by adding an extra log line:

```
console.log("I'm here");
let settings = firebaseDb.ref('userSettings/', function(error) { console.log(error) });
    console.log("Now I'm here");
    settings.on('value', (snapshot) => {
        const data = snapshot.val();
        console.log(data)
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
})
```

While you'll see:

> I'm here

You'll never see:

> Now I'm here

To fix this, remove the extraneous callback and just attach the listener right after you create the reference (which is not an asynchronous operation):

```
console.log("I'm here");
let settings = firebaseDb.ref('userSettings/')console.log(error) });
settings.on('value', (snapshot) => {
    const data = snapshot.val();
    console.log(data)
}, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```